# Selenium Tests run very slow on Internet Explorer

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer-11

I am writing automated tests for my app. Tests are running fine on google chrome. But when I run them on Internet Explorer 11, they run very slow. When I run them on chrome, one test case completes in almost 5 minutes. But on IE11, I have run a single test case for almost 3 hours and tests was on just 2nd steps. I have tried following thing to make them faster

1. I used 32 bit Internet Explorer drivers (I am using 64 bit windows). It is working fast as compared to 64 bit driver but still it is very slow.
2. XPATH is slow as compared to CSS locators so I replaced all XPATH locators with CSS locators. It improves speed in Chrome but for Internet Explorer, there is not much difference in speed as compared to before.
3. I tried to run some simple scripts on other websites for Internet Explorer and they were working fine. But when I wrote similar script for myapp where I was just opening some page and clicking a button and it took more than 10 minutes while on Chrome, it took less than 1 minute.
4. I am not using any implicit waits (hard coded wait like telling code to stop execution for 5 seconds). Instead in all code, I am using wait on the basis of visibility of some element. This has improved time for Chrome and Firefox but for Internet Explorer, speed does not improve.
5. I also modify my code in order to decrease redundant access to DOM but this also does not decrease test time.

Can any one guide me how can I make my test cases faster? My app is written in AngularJS and I do not have any access to the code of App. All I can do is on the test side to make them faster.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this github comment:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5116#issuecomment-192106534

*I think this might be a problem or,

May be javascript is creating issue, try to disable it during your test and see if helps

and try this code too,

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
options.RequireWindowFocus = true;
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

sorry I'm not familiar with python, please convert the code and try..

Comment: I have tried 32bit driver. It is faster than 64bit driver but still it is very slow. I mentioned it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found that calls to FindElements took a really long time and just by setting this **InternetExplorerOptions** below it sped thing up a lot.

```html
var ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
ieOptions.EnablePersistentHover = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the fix was to switch to the 32 bit version of InternetExplorerDriver.exe
Seemingly named IEDriverServer nowadays, but works if you just rename it to InternetExplorerDriver.exe.